# Are there any android theme visualizer tool available?

Tags: android

Is there any tool which will show android theme composition exactly?

I mean, is that possible to see all the styles/attributes of which theme composed with descriptions where they were taken from?

E.g., i would like to see all attributes and values in the theme, say, Theme.Sherlock.Light, with regard to the android version, screen size/position/density etc - is that possible without manually digging through different [styles|atts|dimens|themes|...].xml?